# Remap org-shiftmetaright | org-shiftmetaleft to [shift-select-meta]left-word | [shift-select-meta]right-word]

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Could someone please give me a hand remapping `org-shiftmetaright` | `org-shiftmetaleft` to `[shift-select-meta]left-word` | `[shift-select-meta]right-word]`.  The goal is to highlight select region being a whole word (right or left) in one fell swoop in org-mode instead of changing the level of the headings.  And not highlight when I release the shift, but nevertheless jump whole words to the left or right.

I would imagine that `left-word` and `right-word` probably have that caret `"^"` in the interactive command, or something similar, so there is no separate function for shift-left-word or shift-right-word.

```
(defvar custom-keys-mode-map (make-keymap) "custom-keys-mode keymap.")

(define-minor-mode custom-keys-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  t " my-keys" 'custom-keys-mode-map)

(custom-keys-mode 1)

(defun my-minibuffer-setup-hook ()
  (custom-keys-mode 0))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-setup-hook)

(defadvice load (after give-my-keybindings-priority)
  "Try to ensure that my keybindings always have priority."
  (if (not (eq (car (car minor-mode-map-alist)) 'custom-keys-mode))
      (let ((mykeys (assq 'custom-keys-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
        (assq-delete-all 'custom-keys-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
        (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys))))

(ad-activate 'load)

;; (define-key custom-keys-mode-map (kbd "<C-key>") 'some-command)

(define-key custom-keys-mode-map (kbd "M-<left>") 'left-word)
(define-key custom-keys-mode-map (kbd "M-<right>") 'right-word)

(define-key custom-keys-mode-map (kbd "M-S-<left>") 'left-word)
(define-key custom-keys-mode-map (kbd "M-S-<right>") 'right-word)
```

---

EDIT:  Here is the function from bindings.el that I'm looking to use in org-mode:

```
(defun right-word (&optional n)
  "Move point N words to the right (to the left if N is negative).

Depending on the bidirectional context, this may move either forward
or backward in the buffer.  This is in contrast with \\[forward-word]
and \\[backward-word], which see.

Value is normally t.
If an edge of the buffer or a field boundary is reached, point is left there
there and the function returns nil.  Field boundaries are not noticed
if `inhibit-field-text-motion' is non-nil."
  (interactive "^p")
  (if (eq (current-bidi-paragraph-direction) 'left-to-right)
      (forward-word n)
    (backward-word n)))

(defun left-word (&optional n)
  "Move point N words to the left (to the right if N is negative).

Depending on the bidirectional context, this may move either backward
or forward in the buffer.  This is in contrast with \\[backward-word]
and \\[forward-word], which see.

Value is normally t.
If an edge of the buffer or a field boundary is reached, point is left there
there and the function returns nil.  Field boundaries are not noticed
if `inhibit-field-text-motion' is non-nil."
  (interactive "^p")
  (if (eq (current-bidi-paragraph-direction) 'left-to-right)
      (backward-word n)
    (forward-word n)))
```

Comment: `org-shiftmetaleft` is a function. `[shift-select-meta]left-word` is...?

Comment: That is my way of saying:  shift+alt+left and shift+alt+right  Those are what highlights/selects a word to left or right on OSX, and I think Windows also (but it has been a long time since I've used that OS).  Essentially, I just need to disable the org-mode mapping of those keys and my previous attempts at disabling didn't work, so I thought of remapping.

Comment: Better to use `C-h k` or `C-h c` to ask Emacs how to represent keys. `<M-S-left>` in this case.

Comment: That is `left-word` which activates the `"^"` part of the interactive command so that it selects the region also.  It works perfectly in text-mode and latex-mode, but org-mode overrides it.

Comment: I've added as an edit to my question the function I'm looking to use in org-mode, which is presently being trumped and I'm trying to un-trump it.

Comment: Do you just want `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-left>") nil)` for each of `<M-S-left>`, `<M-S-right>`, `<M-left>`, `<M-right>` ?

Comment: `(void-variable org-mode-map)`

Comment: Well *after* `org` has loaded, naturally. Use `org-mode-hook` or do `(eval-after-load "org" '(progn ...))`

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!!!  And you've also preserved my ability to use `(setq org-support-shift-select t)`.  This method of un-trumping key bindings is definitely a keeper.  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you just want to fall back to the default behaviour for these bindings, we can simply remove the org-mode overrides.

```el
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-left>") nil)
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-right>") nil)
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") nil)
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)))
```

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.  Without this thread, I would have a mess of my init.el file by remapping a bunch of keys without understanding alternative methods to unset mode specific bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not I wanted to do this also. I followed the above - I also re-bound those commands to the C- key:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
'(progn
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-left>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") nil)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-right] 'org-shiftmetaright)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-left] 'org-shiftmetaleft)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-right] 'org-metaright)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-left] 'org-metaleft)
 (define-key org-mode-map [C-S-return] 'org-insert-todo-heading)
 ))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just set `(setq org-replace-disputed-keys t)`, org-mode will remap those conflicting keys. It is also preferable since you can still use Shift + Arrow keys in date selection.

Please see http://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html for more information.